# Question immediately rejected on networkengineering.stackexchange.com for content irrelevant to the question

Tags: discussion, moderation

I don't spend much time on meta. So please give me a chance. I've been referred here by a mod.

I took time to write up a detailed question, for a very specific network related question on auth methods.

It was immediately closed as off topic. Personally I'm really taken back by that. I've been asking questions on Stack sites for a long time, and spent a great deal of time pandering to egos along the way... I have formed this question to be as specific as possible, adhering to everything I have had beaten in to me over the years.

After all the snaps and rude comments, that frankly far too many people experience, playing into the well trodden reputation of curt unhelpfullness by some experts in this ecosystem... Please remember... this is a place to come if you need help. There is a real issue here about soap boxing by community stallwarts, that aside I'll get to the point...

[AP roaming is not smooth for similar authentication methods](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/ap-roaming-is-not-smooth-for-similar-authentication-methods)

How can this question be closed on the basis that it includes "consumer grade" equipment when it's about auth methods in general? How can the fact the networkengineering.stackexchange.com doesn't support clients, disqualify the question? I had even addressed that in my question!

Any helpful advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh sorry. That link is dead. Is it correct? That's why I came here. I thought it was mistyped.

Comment: What link is dead? The one I just provided goes to that site's meta.

Comment: You already have multiple answers to this question on the other site, along with the banner stating the close reason the moderator has gone out of their way to give you a [personal reply](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/ap-roaming-is-not-smooth-for-similar-authentication-methods#comment116944_65543).

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! As this question is about a situation on *one specific site* in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Each site has a *per-site meta* where you can ask questions about that site, which can be accessed through the site switcher on the top right corner. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site.

Comment: @n8te it's dead for me "We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified." Your link, and the mods link from the other site. Sigh. This is closed as off topic too. Not my day.

Comment: Try accessing that link again; it seems that there may have been a brief outage for non-North American users. If it still doesn't work, please let us know, and consider filing a bug report on this site. You *should* be able to access it; the fact that you can't is a bug.

Comment: In any case, though, the fact that you can't post on the correct site doesn't mean that this question is on-topic for this site. I've flagged this question for migration to that site, but that might take a while because normal users can't migrate from here, only moderators can.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog link is still down in Australia and New Zealand. I'm obviously to welcome round those parts, nor these, nor Network Engineering SE. It's been emotional.

Comment: I'm from Australia and that link isn't dead now